# Cannot create OS terminal with jline3

Tags: java, macos, terminal, jline3

In macOS 11.6 running this passing junit test, where Terminal and TerminalBuilder are from jline3:

```
@Test
    void test1() throws IOException {
        Terminal t = getTerminal();
        Assertions.assertNotNull(t);
    }
```

getTerminal:

```
public Terminal getTerminal() throws IOException {
        return TerminalBuilder.terminal();
    }
```

Alternative getTerminal:

```
public Terminal getTerminal() throws IOException {
        return TerminalBuilder.builder().system(true).build();
    }
```

I'm getting this warning message in the console with either version of getTerminal:

> WARNING: Unable to create a system terminal, creating a dumb terminal (enable debug logging for more information)

Obviously I want a system terminal. I have both Jansi and JNA on the classpath as well as the full jline3. I tried running inside Eclipse and from the command line with maven. Results are the same.

Any suggestions on how to get a system terminal?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run your app on command line in order to get system terminal because `System.in` and `System.out` must be attached to your console. This is not a case when you run junit test and probably neither when launching app using maven.

You should write an app and launch it using `java` command in order to get system terminal.

Comment: Thanks @mattirn. I've selected to not use jline with this project for now, but for when I'll use it this is quite useful.